# Missing required architecture x86_64 in file - simulator

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run the app on the device, it works.

But when I run it on simulator, it gives a number of errors.

I am using Pods in my project.

**WARNINGS**

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/aaa/Documents/xxx/bbb' ld: warning: ignoring file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices.tbd,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices.tbd
>   (3 slices) ld: warning: ignoring file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics.tbd,
>   missing required architecture x86_64 in file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics.tbd (3
>   slices) ld: warning: ignoring file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/Foundation.framework/Foundation.tbd, missing
>   required architecture x86_64 in file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/Foundation.framework/Foundation.tbd (3
>   slices) ld: warning: ignoring file
>
> /Users/xxxx/Documents/x/UIKit.framework/UIKit.tbd, missing required
>   architecture x86_64 in file
>
> /Users/aaa/Documents/xxxx/UIKit.framework/UIKit.tbd (3 slices)

**ERRORS**

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITextField", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in CheckOutViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableString", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in NSData+Conversion.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIToolbar", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in CheckOutViewController.o   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UITabBarController", referenced from:
>         _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CustomTabBarViewController in CustomTabBarViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UITabBarController",
>   referenced from:
>         _OBJC_CLASS_$_CustomTabBarViewController in CustomTabBarViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIBezierPath",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UISegmentedControl", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in HomeViewController.o

**Frameworks**

[image]

**Build Settings**

[image]

Pods

[image]

Comment: So what happens if you change Yes to No?

Comment: Then it cannot able to find "import <>" headers.

Comment: @matt, if you check at the bottom of my question, I have just added a file which is being red highlighted in the pods project. Can that be the issue? If yes, how could I able to resolve it?

Comment: It looks like the way you are importing / linking frameworks is perhaps wrong. Look at the linked frameworks in the build phases.

Comment: OK but your question didn't mention any pods. Please revise to say the truth about what you're doing. Thanks! Perhaps you just need a newer rebuilt version of the pods.

Comment: But it works on actual device, why does not work on simulator?

Comment: I think simulator support different architecture than real device. you need to add i386 architecture in valid architecture list.

Comment: Where do I need to add? what is the script ?

Comment: Basically, it should be required with your application target's build settings.

Comment: The thing is that this has been asked many times before, and it is hard to see how this re-asking of the same question adds anything to the mix: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Missing+required+architecture+x86_64+simulator